# BigQuery example for current Google API in PHP

Tags: php, google-bigquery, google-api-php-client

All the question about examples are like 2 years old, and I can't find ANY working example for current API client version (https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client). Every single one is missing something or throwing exception....

Could anybody provide working example? There is no documentation AT ALL, anywhere.

This is the most working one:

```
<?php
    require_once 'inc/google-api/autoload.php'; // or wherever autoload.php is located

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("whatever");
    $client->setDeveloperKey("some key");

    $service = new Google_Service_Bigquery($client);



    $postBody = "[
            'datasetReference' => [
                    'datasetId' => $datasetId,
                    'projectId' => $projectId,
            ],
            'friendlyName' => $name,
            'description' => $description,
            'access' => [
                    ['role' => 'READER', 'specialGroup' => 'projectReaders'],
                    ['role' => 'WRITER', 'specialGroup' => 'projectWriters'],
                    ['role' => 'OWNER', 'specialGroup' => 'projectOwners'],
            ],
    ]";

    $dataset = $service->datasets->insert($projectId, new Google_Dataset($postBody));

    $postBody = "[
            'tableReference' => [
                    'projectId' => 'test_project_id',
                    'datasetId' => 'test_data_set',
                    'tableId' => 'test_data_table'
            ]
    ]";

    $table = $service->tables->insert($projectId, $datasetId, new Google_Table($postBody));
?>
```

But I am getting `Fatal errors` about `Google_Dataset` and `Google_Table` not defined...

Comment: That is not an answer, as I do know how to comunicate with API itself, but not with BigQuery.

Comment: It is more complicated than you think, and I don't want Oauth method, but KEY one...

Comment: But it is not a public key, but server key. Those differ.

Comment: your code wont work because you aren't authenticating.  and you haven't included the Google php client lib.

Comment: I did... please note that new version loads totally different. Autoloader does that. With server key, you don't need any further auth - that's what developer console said.

Comment: It's pretty simple, the library handles all the stuff, just is undocumented how. See my example below.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a code that

- properly creates a `Google_Client`
- runs a job async
- displays the running job ID and status

You need to have:

- service account created (something like `...@developer.gserviceaccount.com`)
- your key file (`.p12`)
- service_token_file_location (writable path to store the JSON from the handshake, it will be valid for 1h)

code sample:

```
function getGoogleClient($data = null) {
    global $service_token_file_location, $key_file_location, $service_account_name;
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");

    $old_service_token = null;
    $service_token = @file_get_contents($service_token_file_location);
    $client->setAccessToken($service_token);
    $key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
    $cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
            $service_account_name, array(
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control'
            ), $key
    );
    $client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
    if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
        $service_token = $client->getAccessToken();
    }
    return $client;
}

$client = getGoogleClient();
$bq = new Google_Service_Bigquery($client);

/**
 * @see https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#resource
 */
$job = new Google_Service_Bigquery_Job();
$config = new Google_Service_Bigquery_JobConfiguration();
$config->setDryRun(false);
$queryConfig = new Google_Service_Bigquery_JobConfigurationQuery();
$config->setQuery($queryConfig);

$job->setConfiguration($config);

$destinationTable = new Google_Service_Bigquery_TableReference();
$destinationTable->setDatasetId(DATASET_ID);
$destinationTable->setProjectId(PROJECT_ID);
$destinationTable->setTableId('table1');

$queryConfig->setDestinationTable($destinationTable);

$sql = "select * from publicdata:samples.github_timeline limit 10";
$queryConfig->setQuery($sql);

try {
//    print_r($job);
//    exit;
    $job = $bq->jobs->insert(PROJECT_ID, $job);

    $status = new Google_Service_Bigquery_JobStatus();
    $status = $job->getStatus();
//    print_r($status);
    if ($status->count() != 0) {
        $err_res = $status->getErrorResult();
        die($err_res->getMessage());
    }
} catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
//print_r($job);
$jr = $job->getJobReference();
//var_dump($jr);
$jobId = $jr['jobId'];
if ($status)
    $state = $status['state'];

echo 'JOBID:' . $jobId . " ";
echo 'STATUS:' . $state;
```

You can grab the results with:

```
$res = $bq->jobs->getQueryResults(PROJECT_ID, $_GET['jobId'], array('timeoutMs' => 1000));

if (!$res->jobComplete) {
    echo "Job not yet complete";
    exit;
}
echo "<p>Total rows: " . $res->totalRows . "</p>\r\n";
//see the results made it as an object ok
//print_r($res);
$rows = $res->getRows();
$r = new Google_Service_Bigquery_TableRow();
$a = array();
foreach ($rows as $r) {
    $r = $r->getF();
    $temp = array();
    foreach ($r as $v) {
        $temp[] = $v->v;
    }
    $a[] = $temp;
}
print_r($a);
```

You can see here the classes that you can use for your other BigQuery calls. When you read the file, please know that file is being generated from other sources, hence it looks strange for PHP, and you need to learn reading it in order to be able to use the methods from it.

https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Service/Bigquery.php

like:

- Google_Service_Bigquery_TableRow

Comment: Hmmm... I've set `$service_account_name = 'xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com';` 
`$key_file_location = 'yyy.p12';` 
`$service_token_file_location = 'tmp';` (directory is writeable) ... but getting error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Could not json decode the token' in .../OAuth2.php:180 ... what am I doing wrong? (of course those are real variables from developer console)

Comment: `$service_token_file_location` = 'tmp' must be a file, not a directory.

Comment: ok, but still the same error when I changed it to writeable file... I guess it nevert gets to moment of using it...

Comment: I just ran the above code and it worked. Maybe some permission or PHP dependencies are missing, but it works.

Comment: Maybe i am giving wrong service account? My is not email... well... changing that to emal didn't change a thing.

Comment: `$client->setAccessToken($service_token);` this is the line that causes error... `$service_token_file_location` should be empty file, right?

Comment: you can modify the code to use $_SESSION in place of the file, that would also work.

Comment: How can I run a synchronus query ?

Comment: One more thing.  If you mess up with your authentication ie wrong service account email you will need to wait like 15 to 20 minutes as Google caches token requests.